# Google Now not Speaking or Executing Comand

Tags: google-account, google-now

My Google Now for some time ago stopped speaking and executing commands.

When I do a command like 'set timer for ten minutes from now' it only searches Google for the text. Same for 'play Jimi Hendrix on YouTube'.

This began to happen when I logged in to Google Now and accepted the new terms.

When I say 'what's the Weather' it shows, but don't speaks out loud. I think that the fact of this working has to be with the google search itself and not the Google Now app.

Language is correctly set for english, and "Speech output" is set to on.

I have seem many other people with this issue googling for this, but yet no real fix.

Android is version `4.2.2` and Google Now is version `5.9.33.16.arm`.

**EDIT**: I have used Tasker + AutoVoice but don't believe this is the problem, because it begin right after I login to Google Now and accept the license; AutoVoice commands in Google Now are not working as well.

Comment: I would try disabling AutoVoice, as it can (and often will) mess with Google Now's functions. It has happened several times for me.

Comment: I've deleted it and even Tasker. I also think it messes up with Google Now.

Comment: Have you tried resetting and/or reinstalling Google Now?

Comment: Yes, even reflashed the same Android.

Comment: Did you try to clear data for the problematic apps and doing a re-login of google account into the phone?

Comment: When I uninstall updates and clear data it begin to work again, even accepting the terms on the old version of Google Now. When I update it stops working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the OP. Reflashing another Android version (currently using Lollipop 5.1.1) "solved" the issue.

Comment: I noticed also that services running as Accessibility makes it even to stop recognizing Voice commands.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (several times).
Latest attempt to fix is to force stop the Google app, disable it. Then enable it again and check all settings.

It worked on my Oneplus 3T, running 7.0. :D